# I'm on Charter's email blacklist, how do I get removed?

Tags: bulk-email, blacklist

I am a programmer in a local government agency. I found out today when I got to work that Charter Internet has blacklisted us for our mailing list that we run. This list is used for communicating news and alerts for our residents. Does anyone have a phone # I can use to contact Charter about this?

Normally the [email approach is fine](http://www.charter.com/postmaster), but we have yet another snow storm coming and 75 of our customers won't be alerted to a snow emergency if we have one and may possibly be towed as a result.

Comment: I guess I can't create the `[blacklist]` tag.

Comment: Sometimes its very difficult to get off a blacklist. I remember a few years ago a spammer got into our server over the weekend. The fastest way to fix it was change our IP address. After securing the server, I used the next IP address and changed the DNS info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Called the number on the link in the original question (1-888-438-2427) and did get a hold of someone that was going to be escalating it to his supervisor. I'll report back if I had any other trouble.

Comment: I never heard back.

Answer (score 2):

Did they resolve the issue for you? Charter uses multiple RBLs. According to their site, "one RBL is intended to keep track of Charter Customers that are known to have been spammers." These customers have allegedly violated the Terms of Service. Another RBL is leveraged to stop inbound mail from spammers at the network layer whose IP blocks are known to be owned by spammers. An IP that is on an RBL will not be able to send email to the Charter mail complex.

So you'll want to be sure to find out which blacklist is causing you problems, as they could have you on the internal blacklist, as well as a third-party blacklist that they are using. You'll also want to find out how you got blacklisted - if it's from a newsletter/alerts customer that doesn't want the emails, then the problem could recur.

Comment: Now that you mention it. No, they did not. I have been too busy with projects at work to even remember.